SQL query counting values in one column, grouped by other columns
My church has a Sunday school program taught by adult volunteers. The children and the volunteers both "check in" to the classroom when they arrive. There is a distinction in the system between "regular" check-ins, and "volunteer" check-ins.
I have three tables that I'm working with for this query: _locations, _check_ins, and _event_times. Here is some sample data for each:
_locations:



_id
_level




1
Nursery


2
Preschool


3
Elementary



_check_ins:



_id
_location_id
_event_time_id
_kind




1
1
1
Regular


2
1
1
Regular


3
1
1
Volunteer


4
2
1
Regular


5
2
1
Regular


6
2
1
Volunteer


7
3
2
Regular


8
3
2
Regular


9
3
2
Volunteer



_event_times:



_id
_time




1
2024-06-16 09:00:00


2
2024-06-16 11:00:00



So far I've got a query that joins them together like this:
SELECT e._time, l._level, count(c._id) service_count
FROM (_locations l
JOIN _check_ins c ON l._id = c._location_id
JOIN _event_times e ON c._event_time_id = e._id)
GROUP BY e._time, l._level

This counts the TOTAL number of check-ins for each room, for each service. But what I would like to do is take it a step further and have two "count" columns. One should have the number of "Regular" check-ins, and the other should have the number of "Volunteer" check-ins. Still per room, per service. How can I achieve this?
Additionally, my query as it stands only shows rows for rooms and services that actually had any check-ins. If a room were to have no check-ins for a particular service, how can I still include that row, and just have the count columns read 0? I think it has something to do with the types of the joins, but I can't figure it out.

Could you not add a WHERE statement for WHERE c._kind = 'Regular' and do another one for WHERE c._kind = 'Volunteer' ?    If you can get one count to work, then you can worry about doing both counts at the same time.  Although perhaps you want to keep this information to use later, you could consider inserting this into a new table to have it all able to be gathered with a simple selete * from thattable in the future.  And you could do insert with the first one, and an update to update the count of the other type column.
